# Connection issue in Isar in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: IsarError: Cannot open Environment: MdbxError (30): Read-only file system

**pubspec.yaml**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ixry.png)

```
name: local_notes
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.3 <4.0.0'

isar_version: &isar_version 3.0.5

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_fonts: ^5.1.0
  lottie: ^2.5.0
  isar: *isar_version
  isar_flutter_libs: *isar_version
  auto_animated: ^3.2.0
  auto_animated_list: ^1.0.4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

  build_runner:
  isar_generator: *isar_version

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
     - assets/animation/
```

I need to connect with Isar without error